# JavaScript Undefined Exception

Tags: javascript, asp.net-mvc, internet-explorer

I am experiencing an annoying error that I only receive in Internet Explorer for some reason.  I have an MVC application and in my `_Layout.cshtml` file I have `@Scripts.Render("~/assets/js/bundled")`.  The bundled seems to be included fine and like I said everything works great in all tested browsers except IE11.  When debugging with in IE I get:

```
0x800a1391 - JavaScript runtime error: 'MyJs' is undefined
```

The javascript file containing the definition for myjs is included in the bundle.  The js (lets call it `myjs.settings.js`)file looks like this:

```
MyJs.settings = (function (parent, window, document, $) {

   function Initialize() { /* do stuff */ }
   function Something() { /* more stuff */ }

   var self = {
      Initialize: Initialize,
      Something: Something,
      Debug: debug
   }

   return self;

} (MyJs, window, document, jQuery));

MyJs.settings.Debug = false;
MyJs.settings.Initialize();
```

Any help would be greatly appreciated. Thanks.

Comment: is `MyJs` previously instantiated? What does `window.MyJs` show in the console?

Comment: thanks for pointing out the obvious...I struggle with it for hours and it was something so simple...man I feel dumb...thanks!!

Comment: still wonder why it worked in firefox and chrome though???

Comment: Firefox and Chrome are more forgivers and usualy will create the instanse on the fly